# What is the CRS for the NOAA GHCN database

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, noaa

The NOAA publishes a Global Historical Climatology Network (GHCN) database having stations with latitude, longitude and elevation. So far, I cannot determine the coordinate reference system. It only says in the [readme](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/readme.txt):

> ```
> LATITUDE     13-20   Real
> LONGITUDE    22-30   Real
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `LATITUDE`   is latitude of the station (in decimal degrees).
>
> `LONGITUDE`  is the longitude of the station (in decimal degrees).
>
> `ELEVATION`  is the elevation of the station (in meters, missing = -999.9).

The coordinates have four digits of precision after the decimal, such as

```
      COUNTRY NETWORK CODE        ID  LATITUDE  LONGITUDE  ...  STATE                    NAME GSN FLAG  HCN/CRN FLAG WMO ID
23763      CA            0  01010066   48.8667  -123.2833  ...     BC             ACTIVE PASS     <NA>           NaN   <NA>
```

I can't really figure out from the readmes or from searching the internet what the coordinate system should be. Should I:

- Assume WGS-84; or
- Assume something else; or
- Take the coordinates of a well-known station whose common CRS representations differ in known ways and choose the one that most closely matches?

This will eventually inform the selection of CRS for GeoPandas processing but that's mostly incidental.

Comment: I would expect WGS84 to be fine for that precision

Comment: 4 decimal places in decimal degres is very roughly 1 second and equal to approximately 31 meters (at the equator or in latitude) to give you an idea of the data's locational accuracy (or not).

Comment: At the end of the readme file there is a contact email address mentioned if you want to be sure...